# response.redirect is not working in node.js which using session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, redirect, express

I have following code in my login page, once the user is authenticated i am redirecting user to the home page.

This code works fine and redirect me to home page but when i add

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));
```

these reference , response.redirect wont work and home page keep loading but response never ends.

```
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    if(request.body.user.name!= undefined && request.body.user.password !=undefined)
    {
        Auth.autoLogin(request.body.user.name, request.body.user.password, function(o){
        if (o != null){
        console.log("Login Successful");                 
                response.redirect('/home'); 
                } else{
        response.render('index', { error-message: 'Login Failed' });
                }
    });
    } 
    else
        console.log("Please enter valid input");
});
```

Please suggest me any solutions

Answer (score 0):

> ...page keep loading but response never ends

This looks like there was sth wrong with your Auth middleware. Page loading happens when next() is not called on middleware, hence there is no response.

Comment: No issue with Auth middleware, I am able to see "Login Successful" message in my console window.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I understand, Auth is setting session through express.session at some point and that seems to be the moment where sth fails.